# Switch goes back to off

Tags: java, android

When turn the switch on it stays on.. however when i leave the activity and come back to it.. it goes back to off. I want it to stay ON OR OFF depending on whats last pressed. I have tried the code below but does not resolve my issue

```
SwitchButton.setChecked(true);
SwitchButton.setChecked(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are minimizing the activity and then returning back to it, and you want all controls to retain their states, then look into implementing saved instance state. This will persist the control values while you minimize / maximize the activity or rotate it. No data is permanently saved to the device. Sample code here:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html#SaveState

If you are closing the app completely and want the app to remember the settings, then consider SharedPreferences, which can be used to save data locally on the device. The data persists until your app explicitly deletes it or you uninstall the app. Sample code here:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is override these methods in your activity:

```
  @Override
  protected void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState){
       super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
       outState.putBoolean("CHECKED", SwitchButton.isChecked());
  }
```

then in onCreate:

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
      super.onCreate(savedInstaceState);

      if(savedInstanceState != null){
          boolean isChecked = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("CHECKED");
          SwitchButton.setChecked(isChecked);
      }
 }
```